# vim filters, piping through multiple commands

Tags: vim, filter, lilypond

I am working with music notation software called `lilypond`.  It is able to
compile text-like notation markup language of it's own, into various formats,
among them `png` file.

Another command which comes with `lilypond` is it's companion
`lilypond-book`, which will compile any document containing `<lilypond>` tag,
and put in that place code snippet like this one:

```
<p>
    <a href="10/lily-9f8f7b5d.ly">
    <img align="middle" border="0" src="10/lily-9f8f7b5d.png"
    alt="[image of music]">
    </a>
</p>
```

So my wish, as a huge fan of `VIM` is to use it's filtering capabilities and
automate this kind of job, so for example when I'm in a document like this
one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>html-with-notation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is some text, before including lilypond notation file

        And here is the melody:
        <lilypondfile>andantino.ly</lilypondfile>/* <-- TAG THAT WILL BE RECOGNIZED BY LILYPOND-BOOK  */

        Enjoy!

    </body>
</html>
```

..I would like to replace that `<lilypond>` tag, with the generated output
from `lilypond-book` command. But it's not that simple, because `lilypond-book`
does not write to a `stdout` but to a file, called `stdin.html`. (it names it
like that automatically, recognizing that the input is comming from there)

So while running this:

```
:.!lilypond-book -f html - 2>/dev/null
        // ( with errors redirected to `/dev/null` to prevent polluting my buffer with messages being output.)
```

I don't get back nothing, which of course is expected, as all of the output has gone to a file.

How would I now read back that `stdin.html` file after all processing is done
from the part of `lilypond-book`, into that current line I am on, in my vim
buffer? All in one go, of course, without doing manually `:r stdin.html`.

Also as a bonus, would it be possible before reading that stdin.html into a buffer, process it with `pandoc` to convert it into a `markdown` first, in cases when I am working on `markdown` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say

```
:.!lilypond-book -f html - 2>/dev/null && cat stdin.html
```

Comment: I never thought of doing that ;) Is it possible after that to append normal mode commands, to indent properly newly inserted code?

Comment: At that point I would probably write a vimscript function for the whole process